Volume by double integration
I had a question while finding the volume of the solid bounded "above" by $f(x,y)=xy$ and bounded "below" by $x^2 + y^2 =9$.
I used double integral in polar coordinate to calculate , then $ V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 \cos\varphi\sin\varphi\ r^3 \,dr \,d\varphi$.
Then i got $ V = \frac{81}{4}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin\varphi\cos\varphi \,d\varphi$. And this integral equals to $0$.
Does this imply that the volume is $0$ or the right way to calculate the volume is $ V = \frac{81}{4}\cdot 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\varphi\cos\varphi \,d\varphi$?

Hint: what symmetries does the volume have?

Please edit your question to include the differentials on your last integral.

Actually your 2nd integral is also missing the differentials.

Take a look at this graph.
https://www.geogebra.org/3d/qqmqbkfs
There's no need to even split into 4 integrals.  One integral is fine.

For your sake, please include the differentials in your actual answer.  I see that you have two previously closed questions out of four previous questions.  They are not my standards but I don't want Math.SE to suspend your account.

Unless you're in or getting ready for graduate analysis, or applying u substitution rule, most differentials are single variables.

@nickalh is it okay now? thank you.

Regarding two segments above and two segments below how does a single "above" segment compare two a single "below" segment.
Also, your use of above and below in your first sentence is confusing.  I think you mean $f$ = the integrand, which varies from positive to negative, and $x^2+y^2=9$ as the outer limit of integration.

No, I think whatever you're trying with the 2nd and 3rd integrals are barking up the wrong tree.  You got that the integral is zero.  Why do you think zero is wrong?

Your 2nd and 3rd integrals were better before your edit.  Why not leave the differential as $d\phi$ after evaluating the first integral?

@nickalh yes, the problem i have that i think that volume cannot be $0$.

First look that the intersection of $z=xy$ with $x^{2}+y^{2}=9$ gives two regions above the $z$ axis and two regions below the $z$ axis. This corresponds to $x,y$ being in the (1st and 3rd quadrants) and $x,y$ being in the (2nd and 4th quadrants).
So by symmetry, you can just consider the 1st quadrant and multiply it by $4$.
In the first quadrant, you are looking at the volume bounded by $z=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$ for $0\leq r\leq 3$ and $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
This gives you that $$\frac{V}{4}=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}r^{2}\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{81}{8}$$
This gives you that $V=\dfrac{81}{2}$
The reason you are getting $0$ is because for $\theta\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and $\theta\in[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi]$, you get intersections in the negative $z$ axis which is giving you negative volume. So when you are adding all $4$, the integral will evaluate to $0$.
Or what you can do is integrate the modulus of the function $xy$.
Then you'll get $$V=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r^{3}|\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)|\,dr\,d\theta$$
and this will give you $V=\dfrac{81}{2}$

@user672587 Suppose you are integrating $\int_{-1}^{0} x,dx$ . Then do you get a postivie value? A similar thing is also happening here.  The reason simply being that $xy$ is negative in those quadrants. Thus, integrating a negative function over any region will give you a negative volume. That is why, if you are asked to find the area bounded by the curve $y=x$ and the $x$-axis for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, you either split it into two and write it as $2\cdot\int_{0}^{1}x,dx$ or you write it as $\int_{-1}^{1},|x|,dx$ because area cannot be a negative quantity. But still $\int_{-1}^{1}x,dx=0$

Oh yes, that's right. It's just that the way I expressed what I thought in the above comment was bad (((

To calculate a volume, we actually need absolute values on the integrand.
$$ V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 |\cos\varphi\sin\varphi\ r^3 |\,dr \,d\varphi$$
becomes
$$V = \frac{81}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} |\cos\varphi\sin\varphi\ | \ d\varphi$$
This is a pretty standard Calculus I integral.
$$V = \frac{81}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \ | \sin2\varphi\ | \,d\varphi$$
Technically, we should split this into 8 integrals, but because each subinterval, $[0,\frac\pi 2), [\frac\pi 2, \pi), [\pi, \frac {3\pi}{2}), [\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi]$ has the same result we merely need integrate one interval and multiply by 4.
Skipping some steps, we arrive at
$$V = \frac{81}{4}\  \frac12 \  \frac12 \ 4(1 -\ -1)= \frac{81}{4} \cdot 2=\frac{81}{2}$$
This is a reasonable result confirmed by intuition when we look at the graph.  I've linked it which will allow you to rotate it and see it from various perspectives.


The reason you are getting $0$ "volume" is that the integral is evaluating the volume of the regions in the 2nd and 4th quadrant to be negative. What you need to do is focus on the 1st and 3rd octants and multiply what you get by $2$ or you can focus on the 1st quadrant only and multiply what you get by $4$. The problem is occuring because you are taking $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Obviously, the volume is not zero.

So either you evaluate the integral of the absolute value of the integrand or you focus on the positive and negative parts separately and then add the absolute values of the result that you get in each region.

Thank you you two so much. I got it now.

Oops, I assumed "net volume" instead of simply volume.  I've almost got a correction posted.

@nickalh You still need to edit it because  you still have a typo of $1-,-1=0$.

Oops, yeah, good catch.
Math.SE seems to have some trouble integrating links and images on the same answer.  If anyone knows a workaround, please edit it into my answer and turn the word "linked" from my last sentence into an actual link.

@nickalh I have edited it. Is this the form that you wanted? For example this is a link to google will give you this is a link to google .

@Mr.GandalfSauron
Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for.  That's not the syntax which M.SE's answer editor generates.  I have that syntax saved in a file for future reference.  Thanks a bunch.
